# How to intercept HTTP OPTIONS calls made by the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, cors, service-worker

I have a use case where I'd like to intercept and log HTTP OPTIONS calls. I understand these are being done by the browser as part of CORS

I've tried monkeypatching XMLHttpRequest, and also a service-worker where I'd intercept via the "fetch" event.

However I am only ever able to capture non OPTIONS calls (GET, PUT, POST)

How can I intercept the OPTIONS calls? I clearly see them being done in the network tab

Comment: I don't think you can do it. This happens internally to the browser, it's not an exposed API.

Comment: @Barmar, if that's the case, do you have any idea how to add any telemetry into CORS requests? Imagine I do a CORS request and the OPTIONS call fails, how am I supposed to know why it failed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the `XMLHttpRequest.status` will contain the error code from the `OPTIONS` call.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, could you link me documentation that says that if possible? I'll also just try to repro this myself to see if that's true

Comment: Sorry, don't know if or where this is documented. But I just assume that if you get a CORS error it will be reflected in the status of the XHR. Where else would it go?

Comment: I think if the OPTIONS request fails it would be due to your server being improperly configured for CORS. So check there first.

Answer (score 2):

CORS preflight requests are hard-coded into browsers as a browser security implementation and are not exposed to us via programmable APIs.  By nature, intercepting or altering preflight requests could negate the security of CORS itself.

Because `OPTIONS` requests are available in Chrome Dev Tools network tab, you can use [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), which uses the Chrome Dev Tools protocol to access lower-level network requests. [`page.setRequestInterception()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) will capture `OPTIONS` requests.

**main.mjs**

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('request', debugRequest);

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    // custom request headers should force preflight CORS requests
    // (see https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests)
    fetch('https://example.com', {
      headers: {
        'force-preflight-request': null
      }
    });
  })

  await browser.close();
})()

function debugRequest(request) {
  console.log(request.method(), request.url())
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! As I understand this is assuming you have control over the browser correct? So this solution couldn't be used when trying to build a client side code, as you don't have control of the browser

However I guess this would work when building for example, some end to end test?

Comment: Correct. I just filed [#1498](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1498) and the spec authors may comment or clarify.